# My .jks file has the true key but my .keystore file does not

Tags: android, google-play

ı am getting wrong SHA1 code in the .keystore file created with this code "keytool -genkeypair -v -storetype PKCS12 -keystore my-upload-key.keystore -alias my-key-alias -keyalg RSA -keysize 2048 -validity 10000" in the Java folder. When such a situation occurs, I encounter an error in Google Play, but the SHA1 code of the .jks file I created is the same as the one given by Google Play. Is it possible to create a .keystore file with the same key signature from a .jks file? Or how can I solve this problem? I can't create aab file without .keystore.

Comment: What does "wrong SHA1 code" mean in this context? How are you computing this SHA1 code? Note that the name of the file extension, whether `.jks` or `.keystore`, is not relevant.

Comment: @PresidentJamesK.Polk My problem is solved, I didn't know they had the same function. I really appreciate you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I changed the extension of the .jks file, which I had previously created in another way, to .keystore without the need to create a .keystore in the Java/jdk/bin folder, and I successfully created my application as an aab file without any problems.